# What's the best long-range antenna for a Baofeng V2N?

Tags: antenna, baofeng

I'm just getting into Amateur Radio, and bought a Baofeng BF-F9 V2N. The antenna's range is about 7-8 miles, but I live in an area where Ham radio isn't very common. Does anybody have recommendations for an antenna to boost range?

Comment: Antennas don't have ranges.  Antenna heights have ranges.  You boost range by using a repeater or an external antenna that is high up.